# c++ instantiate class through template

Tags: c++

Is it possible to achieve something like this? Instead of having different functions that instantiate different classes, it would be nice if it was possible to write one single function that could instantiate different classes if they are derived from the base class and takes the same arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

class Base
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        std::cout << "Oh yes" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{

};

class Derived2 : public Base
{

};

template <typename T>
T* Create<T>()
{
    return new T;
}

int main()
{
    auto* test = Create<Derived1>();
    test->DoSomething();
    delete test;

    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should work. What is your problem?

Comment: Correct your syntax to be `template <typename T> T* Create()`

Comment: And make your `Base::DoSomething` `public`

Comment: oh man I'm ashamed. This does actually work. Cheers guys

Comment: I have rolled back your edit, because it just solved your primary problem, and didn't add any value for future research about similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
void DoSomething()
```

class member function is `private` by default, as it was stated with [vsoftco's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005485/c-instantiate-class-through-template#comment48129526_30005485). Making it `public` may fix your primary (syntactical) issues.

---

**From the semantical point of view:**

Don't use `new`/`new[]`, `delete`/`delete[]` and raw pointers/c-style arrays directly please! Unless you really know you need it, and you want the low level control, it will complicate your code unnecessarily.

For such kind of [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), I'd recommend to use smart pointers from the c++ standard Dynamic memory management facilities:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> Create() {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());
    // Alternatively for c++14
    // return std::make_unique<T>(); 
}
```

The above is the [most simple variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), where the factory method just hands out ownership to the caller.

A real factory might take care of wiring more observers or other stuff up with the created instance, and you'll end up needing some [`std::shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)/[`std::weak_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) idiom instead.

---

Have a tighter look on your code like follows:

```
template <typename T>
T* Create() {
    return new T;
}

int foo() { 
    auto* test = Create<Derived1>();
    test->DoSomething();
    delete test; // what actually happens if Create<Derived1>() or
                 // test->DoSomething(); throws an exception? 
                 // Is the allocated memory tidied up?

    // Irrelevant:
    // std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int retcode = foo(); // Slightly deviated your sample
    // do something else ...
    return retcode;
}
```

Comment: ofc, I was just playing around with the factory function and screwed it up by putting <T> beside the function name = syntax error.

Comment: @nilo Added some links, you might want to read them.

Comment: Why is `Create<T>` not `Create`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ shouldn't be the `unique_ptr` enough? You can construct a `shared_ptr` out of it in case you need shared ownership of the instance returned by the factory (ctor 13 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr))

Comment: @vsoftco Depends a bit of the actual use cases, but basically you're right. I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: Well you made the same mistake as i did in my example, that was the reason my code didn't work :) But than you went on writing a tutorial on smart-pointers which is good but I already know about them. Thanks anyways though

Comment: @nilo So do you have particular reasons to manage some chunk of heap memory on your own? There's still [placement new](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F222557%2Fwhat-uses-are-there-for-placement-new&ei=1xNFVfHxKaLLyAOisICYBw&usg=AFQjCNHiYAXPnKZNjiyku7cLZkR8vnCc_w) and [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) interface, if you really want to do so.

Comment: @nilo _"But than you went on writing a tutorial on smart-pointers which is good ..."_ Yeah well, I know it's good to advise you using smart pointers, that's why I'm doing so. If you have any good reasons you don't want to use them because you have a (rare) use case that's not covered, please elaborate your question.

Comment: The code i posted is just an example code mate. I'm actually creating a 2d game and i'm using smart-pointers but didn't want to post the full code in order to make my point come across easily. Thank you again for your time and good post, didn't mean to be rude :)